# Expression syntax error while compiling in c for my programme

Tags: c, cmd, compiler-errors, command

I got this problem while I'm running the code in command but it worked fine when I used the online compiler.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ky36E.jpg)

All kinds of error I got when I compile in command

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define ARRAY_SIZE 20
#define UPPER_LIMIT 20
#define LOWER_LIMIT 12
#define DATA_UPPER_LIMIT 90
#define DATA_LOWER_LIMIT 10

// randomize and print out number
int randomAndPrint(int array[],int size)
{
    int i;
    array[size];
    // randomize
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        array[i]=(rand()%(DATA_UPPER_LIMIT-DATA_LOWER_LIMIT+1))+DATA_LOWER_LIMIT;
    }
    printf("Bu - Project 3 \n");
    // print size of array
    printf("Sample Size = %d \n", size);
    printf("Array elements:\n");
    // print out element in array
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        printf("%d ",array[i]);
    }
}

// find max and min
int maxAndMin(int array[],int size){
    int min,max,i;
    min=max=array[0];
    // ietrate and find max and min
    for(i=1; i<size; i++)
    {
        if(min>array[i])
         min=array[i];   
        if(max<array[i])
         max=array[i];       
    }
    printf("\nMinimum = %d, ",min);
    printf("Maximum = %d",max);
}

// find average
int average(int array[],int size){
    int i,avr;
    int sum=0;
    // iterate and then sum to find avr
    for(i=0;i< size;i++)
    {
    sum = sum + array[i];
    }
    avr = sum/size;
    printf("\nAverage = %d \n",avr);
} 

// sorting the array
int sort(int array[],int size){
    int x, y, temp,i;
    // check if the element next to each other is bigger then swap 
    for(x = 0; x < size - 1; x++){
        for(y = 0; y < size - x - 1; y++){
            if(array[y] > array[y + 1]){
                temp = array[y];
                array[y] = array[y + 1];
                array[y + 1] = temp;
                for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
                    printf("%d ",array[i]);
                }
                putchar('\n');
            }
        }
    }
}

// finding the median
int findMedian(int array[],int size){
    int avr,middle;
    middle = size/2;
    // check if size is even or odd
    if(size%2==0){
        avr = (array[middle-1]+array[middle])/2;
    }
    else{
        avr = array[middle];
    }
    printf("Median = %d",avr);
}



int main(void)
{
    int sizeOfArray,n;
    srand(time(NULL));
    sizeOfArray = (rand() % (UPPER_LIMIT - LOWER_LIMIT+ 1)) + LOWER_LIMIT;
    // calling each function in the main
    int array[sizeOfArray];
    randomAndPrint(array,sizeOfArray);
    maxAndMin(array,sizeOfArray);
    average(array,sizeOfArray);
    sort(array,sizeOfArray);
    findMedian(array,sizeOfArray);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Please do not post images of text like error messages because they are hard to use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Text should be posted directly **as text** in your question.

Comment: Please mark where in the source code errors are reported. Otherwise everyone has to wade through all that code and check also the unrelated parts. For syntax errors it is normally not required to show all the code that follows in the file. A great poart of the messages that are reported after the first one are typically just a result of the first error.

Comment: Please also add the command you use to compiler yor code.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it works on an online compiler and not on your IDE is because both use different flags to compile the code.

Assuming all your code is in one file, use this:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define ARRAY_SIZE 20
#define UPPER_LIMIT 20
#define LOWER_LIMIT 12
#define DATA_UPPER_LIMIT 90
#define DATA_LOWER_LIMIT 10

// randomize and print out number
static void randomAndPrint(int array[],int size)
{
    // randomize
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        array[i]=(rand()%(DATA_UPPER_LIMIT-DATA_LOWER_LIMIT+1))+DATA_LOWER_LIMIT;
    }
    printf("Bu - Project 3 \n");
    // print size of array
    printf("Sample Size = %d \n", size);
    printf("Array elements:\n");
    // print out element in array
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        printf("%d ",array[i]);
    }
}

// find max and min
static void maxAndMin(int array[],int size){
    int min,max,i;
    min=max=array[0];
    // ietrate and find max and min
    for(i=1; i<size; i++)
    {
        if(min>array[i])
         min=array[i];   
        if(max<array[i])
         max=array[i];       
    }
    printf("\nMinimum = %d, ",min);
    printf("Maximum = %d",max);
}

// find average
static void average(int array[],int size){
    int i,avr;
    int sum=0;
    // iterate and then sum to find avr
    for(i=0;i< size;i++)
    {
    sum = sum + array[i];
    }
    avr = sum/size;
    printf("\nAverage = %d \n",avr);
} 

// sorting the array
static void sort(int array[],int size){
    int x, y, temp;
    // check if the element next to each other is bigger then swap 
    for(x = 0; x < size - 1; x++){
        for(y = 0; y < size - x - 1; y++){
            if(array[y] > array[y + 1]){
                temp = array[y];
                array[y] = array[y + 1];
                array[y + 1] = temp;
                for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
                    printf("%d ",array[i]);
                }
                putchar('\n');
            }
        }
    }
}

// finding the median
static void findMedian(int array[],int size){
    int avr,middle;
    middle = size/2;
    // check if size is even or odd
    if(size%2==0){
        avr = (array[middle-1]+array[middle])/2;
    }
    else{
        avr = array[middle];
    }
    printf("Median = %d",avr);
}



int main(void)
{
    int sizeOfArray;
    srand(time(NULL));
    sizeOfArray = (rand() % (UPPER_LIMIT - LOWER_LIMIT+ 1)) + LOWER_LIMIT;
    // calling each function in the main
    int array[sizeOfArray];
    randomAndPrint(array,sizeOfArray);
    maxAndMin(array,sizeOfArray);
    average(array,sizeOfArray);
    sort(array,sizeOfArray);
    findMedian(array,sizeOfArray);
    return 0;
}
```

`TIP`: make sure to use `void` if your function has no return type. if you put `int` before a function then your compiler will assume that the function is going to return an integer value, which it doesn't. Also, make sure to not declare variables that are not used, as this is really bad practice. Anyway, welcome to SO :)

Comment: To improve that answer you might add an explanation how this solves any of the error messages. Using `void` solves the warnings about missing return value, but none of the errors and other warnings.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just realized it has to do with the compiler I work with and so I had to declare all the variable before I use them. Also, thank you so much for the tips and I will definitely keep them in my head!